# How to addEventListener to all IMG Tags

Tags: javascript

I have a ContentEditable Div Element (Editor).
I want to add EventListener to all Image Tags within the editor.
How can i do the same.
For existing Images i can add using the

```
var imageNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        for(var i=0;i<imageNodes.length;i++) {          
            imageNodes[i].addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',getRemovedNodeDetails,false);
        }
```

For newly entered images how can i do the same. 
Can i add a style to all IMG tag, so that whenever a new image is entered listener will be added to the Tag.

Comment: How are the additional images being added?

Comment: If you can use jQuery, then try using the `.live` function: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @pgpb.padilla live is deprecated

Comment: @AndrewTy. I ahve written logic to add inline images. As i said it is a Sample editor implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this, not because wong's answer is wrong, just a bit too brief..

```
// Warning: Typed on the fly

document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',getRemovedNodeDetails,false);

function getRemovedNodeDetails(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // Yea, there are times tagName returns a lowercase value.
  // I always normalize it for my own sanity.
  if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "IMG") {
    // Now, do something with target
  }
}
```

More details:
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: if you are adding to body, then all the nodes will get this event. I want the event to be handled only for IMG.

Comment: @VeenaSujith -- Answer updated to filter on just `IMG` elements.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding event listeners on every img tag, you could use event delegate to add a event listener on there parent node. This will provide better performance, and more importantly, you can handle newly added images this way naturally.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit.  How can i add it to parent Node.

Comment: Had you googled "javascript event delegate" or "javascript event delegation" it would have taken you to pages of answers.